# Date calculation working fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I'm calculating a difference between two times. This works fine in chrome and firefox, returning the milliseconds difference. It doesn't in Safari, returning difference as NaN.

```
    var currentdate = new Date();
    var myDate = "2018-07-15 21:06:00";
    var difference = (currentdate - new Date(myDate))/3600000;
```

Thanks

Comment: Technically that's not a valid ISO date format is why. Different browsers handle non standard formats differently

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@charlietfl is correct. Try the ISO format

```
var currentdate = new Date();
var myDate = "2018-07-15T21:06:00.000Z";
var difference = (currentdate - new Date(myDate))/3600000;
```

Comment: Hi @doug Coburn , that won't work. It messes up the difference across all browsers (reduces it).

Comment: @flowover9. Which browser is giving the incorrect result?  I'm currently getting about 24.5 as a value for difference in chrome, safari, and firefox.